# How to avoid "jumpy" UI updates?

Tags: javascript

I want to run simulations and update a progress bar, but the progress bar gets updated in a "jumpy" way. Eg. it moves from 21% to 34% to 76%. I'd like to to move one-by-one from 21% to 22% to 23% etc.

Consider this as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

http://embed.plnkr.co/XIKxpV6oWyWiwklFBSLh/

**HTML**

```
<button>Simulate</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $button = $('button');

  var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
  worker.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if (e.data) {
      switch (e.data.cmd) {
        case "progress":
          $button.text((e.data.value / 250).toFixed(0) + "%");
          break;
        case "complete":
          $button.text("Simulate");
          break;
      }
    }
  });
  $button.on("click", function() {
    worker.postMessage("start");
  });
});
```

**Worker**

```
this.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  if (e.data === "start") {
    for (var n = 0; n < 250000000; ++n) {
      if (n % 10000 === 1) {
        this.postMessage({cmd: "progress", value: n / 10000});
      }
    }
    this.postMessage({cmd: "complete"});
  }
});
```

How can I get it to update smoothly? Why isn't it updating smoothly to begin with?

Comment: Have you considered CSS animations to accomplish this?

Comment: @stealththeninja I haven't. To be honest, I'm not too familiar with them. Would they solve the problem?

Comment: @stealththeninja CSS animations to *smoothly increment text*...?

Comment: My mistake, I read "progress bar" and assumed incorrectly.

Comment: I'd suspect it's some issue with the layout/rendering engine not updating frequently enough to capture each increment. If you change `$button.text((e.data.value / 250).toFixed(0) + "%");` to `setTimeout(function() { $button.text((e.data.value / 250).toFixed(0) + "%"); });` instead, does that improve it at all? (Granted, it may break your `"complete"`)

Answer (score 0):

You could change `progress` to provide fill values.

The reason why it's not smooth is that it doesn't post a progress value for all values, only every `10000` (if you try to post every value it's very likely your browser is going to freeze)

```
if (n % 10000 === 1) {
  this.postMessage({cmd: "progress", value: n / 10000});
}
```

So you don't get all possible % values, you need to fill.

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $button = $('button');

  var last = 0
  var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
  worker.addEventListener("message", function process(e) {
    if (e.data) {
      switch (e.data.cmd) {
        case "progress":
          var next = (e.data.value / 250)
          var current = last

          // fill values
          // from last % to new %
          for (; current < next; ++current) {
            $button.text(current + "%")
          }

          last = current

          $button.text(next.toFixed(0) + "%");

          break;
        case "complete":
          $button.text("Simulate");
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  $button.on("click", function() {
    worker.postMessage("start");
  });
});
```